# Hibernate different name of foreign key column

Tags: hibernate

I got in DB tables:
a) rb_user:
id_user, username, ...
b) rb_user_password:
id, user_id, password.

How to annotate this in my java classes? I got:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="rb_users")
@SecondaryTable(name="rb_user_password")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id_user")
    private int id;
    private String name;
    ...
    @Column(table="rb_user_password", name="password")
    private String password
```

I got these exception:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column user0_1_.id_user does
>   not exist

I know its because I got primary key "id_user", and in my table with password column name is "user_id"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specifiy the name of the attribute in the secondary table with the [`pkJoinColumns`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/persistence/SecondaryTable.html#pkJoinColumns%28%29) attribute on `@SecondaryTable`.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="rb_users")
@SecondaryTable(name="rb_user_password", pkJoinColumns=@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="user_id"))
public class User {
...
}
```